# Facebook - Create New App button does not exist anywhere

Tags: facebook

I have a verified (via credit card) Fan page, and would like to add a tab with iFrame content.  Looked on the web and found numerous tutorials.  In each tutorial, it describes to:

Go to http://facebook.com/developers, and then click the Create New App button.

But, when I go to this link, it just takes me straight to my Facebook Fan Page??

Another tutorial tells me to:

Go to http://developers.facebook.com (this works), then click Apps on the top menu.  But when I click Apps, once again, I am directed straight to my Facebook Fan Page.

In effect, there is absolutely NO 'Create New App' button, anywhere - and attempting to reach it using the methods above results in redirection to my Fan Page.

My account is verified.  Is there anything else that might cause this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you might want to check if you are logged in as the facebook user and not using facebook as the page. In case you are logged in as the administrator account then check if you have blocked the facebook apps in your account settings->apps.

Comment: How is this off topic when I am trying to get to the point of creating an application???  And, why aren't other questions similar to this then closed for the same reason??  Anyway, thank you for your response BST I will check on those issues...

Comment: Why was this closed? The thing I hate about SO is the extraordinary practice of closing valid questions. I have the same problem, and I can't ask the Facebook community because the link to it takes me to my Fan Page?!?

Comment: The answer for me is that my FB page was created without having another FB account as admin - it stands alone. So now I've created a FB account and am trying to link it back as the owner of the page. Grrr. Not liking FB dev so far.