# Is it possible to "Create New App" beeing an admin/manager of a company/artist facebook site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, administration

We start to admin/manage several facebook company/artist pages. Is it possible to create apps 
("Create New App") while beeing admin/manager of several facebook sites? We like to integrate 
websites to facebook company/artist pages (while beeing Admin/Manager and facebook developer).

Thanks for any info, for us it seems not quite possible to do that. When clickcing the "Create
New App Button" (or Apps in the menubar) it jumps back to the admin site selection screen with 
all the pages (my sites) listet. Maybe we missed out something, what should we do? (Facebook
apps are not blocked in the account settings)

Many regards

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Facebook app only and only if you are using a regular Facebook User account not a business account like the one you are using in your question. You can refer to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798697/facebook-create-new-app-button-does-not-exist-anywhere) as mentioned in comment on your question

Comment: Thanks. We have missed that. It might explain much.